# ADT Eclipse imports cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm working on some Android projects for school and I brought them home to work on over the weekend. I downloaded ADT/Eclipse on my desktop here and picked the folder my projects are in as the workspace.

When I open up the classes in the project to work I just see loads of errors in the code, which stem from errors shown in the imports like

```
    import android.content.Context;
```

Imagine error marks under "android.content". It's like this with all of imports and when I hover over them the little window says "The xxxx.xxxx cannot be resolved". I'm currently API 19 on my desktop here.

What's the problem here?

Oh, and another thing: in the little console tab-window it says "Unable to resolve target 'android-18'". Could this a cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have ADT installed, you probably don't have API 18 installed. You can install it from the SDK manager in Eclipse.

Another option is to change the app to compile with API 19.

Right click your project > Properties > Android > Select the version to compile with

Comment: Yup that fixed it. I'm still pretty green when it comes to working with eclipse. Visual Studio has spoiled me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should install latest ADT Bundle from Android official website that is available at :`http://developer.android.com`

and after downloading , don't extract it to desktop , instead extract it to the folder where you have installed Java JDK(java Development Kit). Because PATH might be the problem..